# Extruding mesh with holes creates weird artifacts

Tags: mesh, faces, geometry, extrude

[image: Ho]

I created slits in my chair mesh by subdividing then deleting faces. I wanted to a little thickness to the chair by extruding by normals. However, it created these weird artifacts.

[image]

Cleaning up the mesh by merge by distance or flipping normals doesn't do the trick. Are there any solutions to this dilemma?

Comment: you probably need to add some edges, please show the wireframe or share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Or, depending on where you're going with the model later, in the object's Data tab > 'Normals' panel you might just want to turn on 'Auto Smooth'  with an angle that catches the curve, but not the slot.

Comment: @moonboots Sending you the blend file here:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6442" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6442/)

Comment: @RobinBetts Tried doing what you suggested, but the artifacts remain. Tried to thicken the mesh through modifiers but it worsened it. Thinking I've messed up the geometry somewhere. I've sent the blend file up above, so others may take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have ngons that create this kind of artefacts. Also you have a lot of useless edges, if you use a *Subdivision Surfaces* modifier you won't need so many.

If I were you I would redo the object, it would take less time than correct your version:

- Keep the profile only, mirror it, use the *Checker Deselect* and the *Dissolve Vertices* tool to keep only the necessary amount of vertices.

[image]

- Now extrude the profile, give it some edge loops and bevel where the cut are supposed to happen, then delete the faces.

[image]

- Give it some additional edge loops to make the holes square, give your object a *Solidify* modifier to give it thickness, keep a copy of the object somewhere, apply the *Solidify* modifier, bring some additional edge loops to sharp the edges again.

[image]